# GitHub equivelant to GitLab review apps

Tags: github

GitLab has an extremely useful feature called [Review Apps](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/review_apps/) which allows you to start up an instance of the web app from every PR which has its own subdomain and is linked on the PR page. I have done some searching and I don't see anything quite like it for GitHub.

Are there any ways to achieve a similar thing on github? 3rd party services are fine if they can integrate in with github. The app has a docker compose config so it would be just starting up an instance on a VM and shutting it down later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest would be [Delivering deployments](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/delivering-deployments)/[Deployment API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/deployments), as described in  the article "**Deploy your pull requests with GitHub Actions and GitHub Deployments**" from [**Sander Knape**](https://twitter.com/SanderKnape).

[image: https://sanderknape.com/images/github_deployments_finished.png]

You can see its [workflow here](https://github.com/SanderKnape/pr-deployments/blob/master/.github/workflows/pr-deployment.yaml).

But the point is: there is not a directly integrated "review" deployment process like GitLab: you need to write your own GitHub workflow in order to deploy on a GitHub-managed Azure-based server, starting with:

```yaml
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: deploy-check
    if: needs.deploy-check.outputs.triggered == 'true'
    steps:
      - name: get pull request ref
        id: get_pull_request_ref
        uses: octokit/request-action@v2.x
        with:
          route: GET /repos/:repository/pulls/:issue_id
          repository: ${{ github.repository }}
          issue_id: ${{ github.event.issue.number }}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
```